# A sequence of Bash commands that work in the terminal but not in a script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to remove all special characters with a space except the dot before the extension.
Let's take this file as an example, since I have tons of them.

```
FRD - 2023.04.12 - (mj)_Text and other chars[ ].txt
```

Desired output:

```
FRD 2023 04 12 mj Text and other chars.txt
```

I've written a series of commands that allow me to do just that:

1. Remove all dots except the extension one:

   ```
   rename -v 's/\.(?!(avi|mkv|mp4|mov|wmv|jpg|jpeg|png|txt))/ /g' *
   ```

   Result: `FRD - 2023 04 12 - (mj)_Text and other chars[ ].txt`
2. Remove all other characters except the extension dot:

   ```
   rename -v 's/(([^a-zA-Z\d\s])|(-)|(:))(?!(avi|mkv|mp4|mov|wmv|iso|jpg|jpeg|png|txt))/ /gi' *
   ```

   Result: `FRD   2023 04 12    mj  Text and other chars   .txt`
3. Reduce multiple spaces to a single one:

   ```
   rename -v 's/\s{1,10}/ /g' *
   ```

   Result: `FRD 2023 04 12 mj Text and other chars .txt`
4. And because there were characters just before the extension, remove this space:

   ```
   rename -v 's/(\s+)(?=(\.))//g' *
   ```

   Result: `FRD 2023 04 12 mj Text and other chars.txt`

Now I put all these commands in a script with a for loop. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*; do
    
    rename -v 's/\.(?!(avi|mkv|mp4|mov|wmv|mpg|iso|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|txt))/ /gi' *
    rename -v 's/(([^a-zA-Z\d\s])|(:))(?!(avi|mkv|mp4|mov|wmv|mpg|iso|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|txt))/ /gi' *
    rename -v 's/\s{1,10}/ /g' *
    rename -v 's/(\s+)(?=(\.))//g' *
    
done
```

Here's how it looks using the script:

```
FRD 2023 04 12 Mj Text and Other Chars Txt
```

Why, if all these commands work one after the other, do they not give the same result in a script? What is the problem is?

Comment: If you copy-paste the contents of your script into your terminal, you'll see you get the same result as when running the script.

Comment: _Desired output_ : What do you mean by **output**? You don't seem to print anything.

Comment: In your script, you assign to a variable named `f`, which you never use. While this is not forbidden, doing so nearly always points to an error in logic. Why are you looping over files, if you then don't use the filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the commands individually, you pass `*` to each command, which expands to the current file list. In the script you have a `for` loop, which executes the commands on all files, and repeats for the amount of files. This means that if you have 17 files in the directory, each command will run 17 times on *all* files, which is not what you want.

Simply remove the `for` loop, and keep the commands as they are;

```
#!/bin/bash
rename -v '...x...' *
rename -v '...y...' *
# and so on..
```

(of course, replace `'...x...'`/`'...y...'` with the actual patterns)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

The solution was right there in front of me. It took someone else to see it and everything was fixed! Works perfectly.

Thanks again!